# Problema com TypeScript + Styled-Components

Tags: react, typescript, styled-components

Boa tarde!

Estou começando a utilizar TypeScript e me deparei com alguns problemas na configuração do projeto React, utilizando TypeScript e Styled-Components!
Estou utilizando declaração de módulo, extendendo o tema e aplicando generics para os tipos, mas eles são simplesmente ignorados!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o erro acima, como pode ver, o "theme" está funcionando corretamente, no entanto, as propriedades link, hasIcon, etc, estão sendo ignoradas mesmo havendo uma interface dentro do styled.

Alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Para usar as props no seu **Button**, use uma **interface** ao invés do **type**, inclusive, podes declarar também o *theme* e o *disabled* nela, oque torna mais explicito sobre oque essa interface significa.

Experimente substituir o **type** por isso:

```
interface TStyles {
    fullWidth: boolean
    hasIcon: boolean
    margin: string
    disabled: boolean
    theme: SEU_TIPO_DE_TEMA_UTILIZADO
}
```